# Arduino LCD Simple Problem

Tags: arduino-mega, lcd

Hi my lcd doesnt display that i was expected. Can anyone help me???

RS-->22
RW-->GROUND
E-->23
D4-->24
D5-->25
D6-->26
D7-->27

```
    #include <LiquidCrystal.h>

LiquidCrystal lcd(22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27);
void setup() {

lcd.begin(16,2);

lcd.setCursor(0,1);
lcd.print("Hello!");
delay(1000);
}
void loop() {
lcd.setCursor(0,1);
lcd.print(millis()/1000);
}
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried turning the trim pot? It could be a contrast issue

Comment: yes. i add lcd clear commant and shakes the cables and the problem is solved!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I Had a similar problem with a different display, It looks like you are printing the value without clearing the display so all the numbers print on top of each other creating those squares. try adding lcd.clear() in the loop to clear the display before it prints another value.